# How do I make JButton open different frames?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have created 2 JButtons but both open the same file how do i make the second button open another file........................................................................................................................................................

```
//Starting Page

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt. *;
import java.io.*;


   public class AddressBook implements ActionListener     // Create a new class Address Book
{
    JFrame Start=new JFrame("Address Book");     // Set name of Frame
    JButton Open;              // Set new button
    JButton Second;
 {
      Open=new JButton("OPEN");     // set name of button
      Second=new JButton("Second");
      Start.setSize(500,600);       // set size of frame
      Start.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("backgroundforlab.jpg")));      // add background picture
      Start.setVisible(true); 
      Start.setLayout(null);
      Start.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);  
      Start.getContentPane().add(Open);                           //Make button visible
      Start.getContentPane().add(Second); 
      Open.setBounds(100,385,295,88);  
      Second.setBounds(50,160,150,44);                           // set size of button
      Open.addActionListener(this);
      Second.addActionListener(this);

 }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
      Start.dispose();              // When button is clicked close frame and open mainMenu 
      mainMenu A=new mainMenu();    
}

   public static void main(String ag[])
  {
      AddressBook A=new AddressBook();          // run class AddressBook
  }  


}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) The most logical alternative for this case would be to use `JDialog` for the child windows.

Comment: Hmm, I just started using java so I don't understand much, i'm doing a school project which i need to create multiple jframes, thanks for the advice though.

Comment: *"i need to create multiple jframes"* I really doubt that (they explicitly stated `JFrame`). To recommend that to students would be extreme incompetence.

Comment: oh haha, not jframe but more than one window you could say, this is for my grade 12 culminating, teaching my self how to use Jbuttons, jframes, etc.

Comment: *"more than one window"* Well, as implied by my first comment, a `JDialog` **is a window**. It's just much better suited to being a window that has a parent window (such as a `JFrame`)

Comment: ohhh ok, i understand now. Thanks, for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You could...

Use separate `ActionListener`s for your buttons

```
Open.addActionListener(new OpenActionListener());
Second.addActionListener(new SecondActionListener());
```

You'll need to supply the implementations of the `ActionListener`s as additional classes

This is probably one of the preferred methods, as it isolates functionality/responsibility for the action to a single class, but it does create a bunch of small class.

## You could..

Use anonymous classes instead...

```
Open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Overrride
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
    }
});
```

This is basically the same idea as before, but it doesn't require a separate class to manage

## You could...

Use the `actionCommand` property to identify the buttons

```
Open.setActionCommand("open");
Second.setActionCommand("second");

//...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  String command = e.getActionCommand();
  if ("open".equals(command)) {
      //...
  } else if ("second".equals(command)) {
      //...
  }
}
```

This is good if you have a number of buttons which repeat actions (like menus and toolbar buttons)

## You could...

Use the `source` property to identify the buttons

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Object source = e.getSource();
  if (source == open) {
      //...
  } else if (source == second) {
      //...
  }
}
```

This will only work if the `ActionListener` has access to the actually references to the buttons.  This makes it limited in it's use, especially since there are better solutions available

You should also have a look at:

- [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to write `ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

for more details and ideas

Comment: Thanks so much this helped me understand so much more, since i am going to be using lots of buttons i want to use the action command, but i don't know how to use it, sorry i am new to this. I added the action command code you gave, and after the if ("open".equals(command)) { I added  Start.dispose(); the program runs with no error but nothing happens once i click the button. I know im missing something but i don't  know what, i tried searching how to use action command, but i don;t understand how to use it in my code. A little guidance would be really helpful . Thanks

Comment: Add the above code to the same place you create/add your buttons

Comment: I have already done that, i am not sure what to type in after the if ("open".equals(command)) {
      //...

Comment: What ever action you want to take when the button with the `"open"` command is actioned

Comment: Yes, i added Start.dispose(); to close the frame nut nothing happens when i click the button.

Comment: I've tested your code and I can verify that the `actionListener` is called and prints out the correct `actionCommand`

Comment: OMG I finally figured it out, when you told me to add Open.setActionCommand("open"); I was taking out Open.addActionListener(this); and replacing it with Open.setActionCommand("open"); . WOW. I need both, such a stupid mistake. Thank you for helping me this far, I know some people whould have already stopped helping me at this point, lol sorry.